Baseline for sanity?
I'll be honest, I've not been studying psychology seriously, but I've read quite a lot of philosophy.
So, I just started reading "Divided Self" by R. D. Laing and right at the very beginning there's this quote.

What is the implication here? "Not being automata" = accepting the concept of free will? Is this the common notion in the field of psychology / therapy?
Or is there for example a "default" position on "ego"?
Because it seems very strange to imply such biases, considering these themes are highly debatable in philosophy/different religions/countries/etc.

There are so many problems with this paragraph (e.g. Peoples ARE animal, saying that (only) some "experience themselves as animals" is problematic in itself), I would just ignore it.
